# Why when we read from two Torah scrolls is the one taken out first returned last and vice versa?

Tags: sefer-torah, ark-aron-kodesh

When we Askenazim read from two Torah scrolls, the one taken out first is returned last and the one taken out second is returned first.

But we say “maalin bekodesh ve’ain moridin” – we go up in holiness and not down. So why do we degrade the first sefer by returning it second.

In case you argue that being out is the holiness of the sefer, then the question becomes why do we reduce the time that the second sefer is out by returning it first?

Not deliberately Purim Torah!

Comment: Is it possible this is just because of how the scrolls fit in the ark? i.e. there is just no room to get the second one in there if the first one is in the way? (Personally I've never noticed any particular order of how they return them, but I'm planning on paying attention.)

Comment: Agree with Ariel. It's a practical custom (as quite a few are). It could also be rationalized as giving equality in status to the Sifrei Torah - the second one isn't "second best" since it goes back first.

Comment: My guess is that it's the same reason we take tefillin off in the opposite order we put it on.  It doesn't degrade the first sefer to stay out longer - it's a kavod to it.

Comment: I think the correct clall to apply is "Ain MaaVirin Al HaMitzvot" to since we are going to read from the first sefer torah first so that is the one we take hold of first. On the way back since Hagbah was done with the second sefer that is the one we return first as to put it aside  in favor of the first sefer which would be embarrassing it.

Comment: I haven't paid attention to what is done in my shul. It will be a while since we will need to take out 2 SIfrei Torah on Shabbat (I think Rosh Hodesh Ellul, this year.) Surmising - Being the Ba'al Kri'ah, I am also responsible for the placement of the Sifrei Torah in the ark. The "weekly" Torah which is usually the 1st one is in the middle and the others are to the side. So, I think this is to avoid confusion so that they don't put the 2nd in the middle, and then next week they take out the wrong Torah for Shabbat. I'm not always there to direct them when they return the Sifrei Torah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are going to read from the first sefer torah first, that is the one we take hold of first. On the way back since Hagbah was done with the second Sefer that is the one we return first as in theory that is the one currently in the hand.

Source:
http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5770/korach.html note 37

Answer (score 1):

I think it's to show that both Sifrei Torah are equally Kosher and important.

The Shat"z-for-Shachrit carries the first Sefer to the Bima. One could suspect that the Second Sefer is somewhat less *equal*.

The Shatz-for-Mussaf therefore carries the **second** Sefer back to the Aaron HaKodesh. Since it's natural for the Shat"z to lead the *parade* back, the second Sefer gets put back first.

Since both Seforim now had a chance to *be first* - we know for sure that they are equal.